# Why does my InfoPath 2010 form stop opening in the browser when I add a code project?

Tags: infopath, development

I created an InfoPath 2010 form and published it to SharePoint Server 2010.
I published it to open in the browser not in the InfoPath Filler, and it works fine.

When I attach a code project to it (even I don't write any code), it opens with the InfoPath Filler not the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, describe method how you deploy your form.

Comment: This is funny but I have reverse problem - as soon as I attach custom code to a button placed on a browser-enabled form in Infopath Designer 2010 [this button cannot be rendered in Infopath Filler or client form](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/how-to-update-a-sharepoint-2010-list-via-an-infopath-2010-client-form-via-a-code) any more

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the moment you attach a code project to it, it loses its status as a browser-enabled form.  This results in the form defaulting to opening itself in Infopath.  Remove the code project and you should be fine.