# How to update a SharePoint 2010 list via an InfoPath 2010 client form using code?

Tags: 2010, 2007, infopath, list-template, forms-library

I tried to follow in Sharepoint Server 2010 and Infopath 2010 the article:

- [How to update a SharePoint list via an InfoPath browser form using the SharePoint Object Model](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/update-sharepoint-list-items-object-model-infopath-browser-form.htm)

which is for Sharepoint/Infopath 2007  adjusting it for 2010

Upon completing step 7:

- "7. On the Button Properties dialog box, select **Update Form** from the **Action** drop-down, and click **OK**"

I observe the warning:

- The button control will only be visible when the form is edited in a Web browser

[image]

Pressing F5 (or Preview) button (which, as I believe, corresponds to running a form in "Infopath Filler 2010"?) confirms it and shows the form without this button.

How should I interpret the [msdn's comparative table of differences between Infopath 2010 List and Form Library templates](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39289/why-such-differences-between-infopath-2010-templates-for-form-library-and-list) from which one can understand that:

- **custom code** support is available only for Infopath 2010 **Form Library Template** but not for **List Template** while I have a custom code in **List template**?

Should I understand that it is impossible to update a **list form** from client form through SharePoint Object Model?

How one should proceed in order to update a **Sharepoint 2010 list** from an **Infopath 2010 client form** (i.e. in Infopath Filler 2010 or other clients like Outlook) through code?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but your stated understanding is correct.

**A list form CANNOT be converted to a regular InfoPath form.** The list form is a specialized template which is locked to a specific submit datasource (the SharePoint list). There are other limitations to the "list form" template type, as well. This fact isn't overly obvious in most documentation, but is mentioned briefly in the "[Overview of Form Templates](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Overview-of-form-templates-and-modes-29a8ae70-216b-4dc7-8907-55500937e2e5)" article.

Here's the relevant part:

> After selecting a form template from the New tab, InfoPath will
>   default your filling environment (mode) to Web browser or InfoPath
>   Filler. In most cases, you can easily switch between modes by using
>   Save-As, or by clicking the File tab then Form Options. Next, click
>   Compatibility and select the desired form type from the Form type box.
>   **There are, however, a few form templates where the mode cannot be
>   changed, such as SharePoint list and E-mail.** Certain controls, data
>   sources, and templates are also available in only one environment. For
>   example, submit database connections and XML schemas with complex
>   repeating sequences are only supported in the InfoPath Filler.
>   Finally, InfoPath Filler forms contain a superset of the controls and
>   features that are available in Web browser forms. You can add features
>   to a Filler form that will not work in a Web browser form. If you
>   expect a form to be filled out on SharePoint and in the InfoPath
>   Filler, you should design a Web browser form.